# Why isn't Python specific about what the invalid syntax is

Tags: python, syntax

Lets say I have this piece of code:

```
>>> for x in range(10)
File "<stdin>", line 1
for x in range(10)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python points at where the invalid syntax is, but doesn't tell me what is it that I am missing. Note that this question is not about what I am missing. **I do know** that there is a `:` that I am missing at the end of the range() function. I am asking why Python isn't specific about the missing `:`. Is there anything else that can come after the range() function in terms of syntax?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus , this person is conscious about what the error is... he clearly says in his question

Comment: what if you want `for x in range(10), range(12):`?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus My question isn't about what I am missing. It is about why Python chooses not to pin point it.

Comment: @BearBrown That makes sense. I think that's all I needed! Thanks!

Comment: could also be part of a comprehension statement, like `(x for x in range(10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

> The for statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
          ["else" ":" suite]
```

Then, after the `in` you can put any iterable. Specifically answering your question, after the `range()`, you can put a comma and pass any object, or you could also keep passing as many objets as you want separated by commas.